# Object Initialization: Init method or stream operator?

Tags: c++, initialization

`Game Coding Complete 4th ed. by Mike McShaffry and David Graham` (67-68) says that classes should use streams to initialize objects:

```
class AnimationPath
{
    public:
    AnimationPath();
    Initialize(std::vector<AnimationPathPoint> const & srcPath);
    Initialize(InputStream & stream);
    //of course lots more code follows.
};
```

> This class has a default constructor and two ways to initialize it. The first is through a classic parameter list, in this case, a list of `AnimationPathPoint`s. The second initializes the class through a stream object. This is cool because you can initialize objects from a disk, a memory stream or even the network....
>
> (Mr. Graham, the author of the chapter containing the quote, goes on the explain why using a stream as an argument to a constructor is bad. Streams could fail and your object is in a failed state.

My question is, not about using this policy, but why not use the stream operators `operator<<` and `operator>>` in lieu of or in addition to the `Initialize` methods. (The `Initialize` method(s) could even just be delegates of the stream operators.)

Is the difference semantic or is there a legitimate reason to use one over the other?

Comment: `operator<<` is output (from the stream's perspective), so it has nothing to do with initialization. That said, I'd prefer using the constructor to initialize things, not some external function.

Answer (score 3):

`operator<<` and `operator>>` are abominations and one of the larger mistakes of the C++ IOStreams library. Never copy that pattern. Taking an explicit `std::istream&` (or your framework's equivalent) makes far more sense.

An even cleaner approach (not always the most feasible, though) is to have a completely separate `AnimationPathSerializer` that handles mapping streams to `AnimationPath` objects. Keep each type/object small and focused on only a single concern. An animation doesn't need to know how to load or save itself to be an animation, and there may be a time when you want to support several completely different serialization formats with very different semantics (so a single universal stream type or a single serialization interface in the object won't make sense).

Comment: I am highly doubtful about your 1st paragraph. IMHO `operator<<` and `operator>>` are one of the most pleasant things in C++. 
Please explain your point.

Comment: @Sam: They're difficult to use correctly. You have to stream something like `std::dec` to set the _mode_ of the stream, then stream the data, then remember to reset the mode back where it needs to be. Let's not forget show only IOStreams requires parenthesis in unexpected places due to operator precedence of `<<`. The operator syntax adds nothing of value over a `write()` member function; all it does end up teaching newbies to abuse operators.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in a stream to an initialize routine, the stream might already have the `>>` `<<` operators defined and you can make use of them to set member variables within your class.

If you define your own operators it won't be clear exactly what is happening, because you can write whatever code you want within those operators. If someone sees an initialization with a stream it would be reasonable to immediately assume the constructor (or init function) is doing some kind of serialization. This makes the code readable.

Although you don't *have* to use a stream like this, but it is a pretty good way to get started. So if the book actually says you *should* use streams, I'd have to disagree and say you *can* use streams, not *should*.

Comment: The first paragraph of the answer is fine. The second is too Java-ish for me. If this was a valid complaining, then operator overloading would not be allowed. Funny it's not allowed in Java. Anyway, if you keep your project consistent, like `entity << stream` is `Init(Stream)`, to all entities, then you should have no problem on readability. Since it's stated for all co-workers that all entities should accept this form of init.

Answer (score 0):

What they are talking about is serialization. In a game, you most often need a lot of data to make things work your way. How to implement serialization is really very much up to you. Using an std::stream is a good idea because it can point to anything as they mentioned (file, string, network...) But giving each object the authority of handling their own serialized data... not too sure about that!

So the most important part is not so much the `<<` and `>>` operators, but rather how forward and backward compatible you want your serializer to be. This has been the nightmare of most of the people using such mechanisms (even MFC had similar functions!).

So if you use a binary input file, you'll need tools to verify that the file is valid. And when you want to add one field, all the old files are kaput! Unless you spend countless hours at supporting the old format(s) or you use a really extensible format.

So a better approach is to make use of a format that a high level load function can handle and is readily extensible without you having to do any work each time you add a field. If you really want to use a binary format, I would suggest a tagged file, a bit like IFF where you have a structure such as:

```
32 bits    -- tag name
32 bits    -- size
size bytes -- data
```

Flash uses a similar format, "compressing" the tag and size in 16 bits (10 bits for the tag, 6 bits of size), unless the size is too large, then they use another 32 bits (the 6 bits of the size are set to 0x3F in that case.) And of course, they have one loaded that knows how to read that header, but passes the data block to their objects that have to decipher that binary block (which can be a simple struct, though, but remember that computers may be little or big endian...).

When you need to add data, you can grow your 'data' structure. Easy enough, on load you have to make sure you have the correct 'size' and adjust the parameters of your structures accordingly. If you have large blocks of data, you can also consider compressing them. Maybe the tag name changes for the compressed version or you reserve a flag in there for that purpose.

Another format, very much used with games too, is XML. Many people do not like it because the parsing is heavy (as in "slow") but it is definitively extensible.

In both those cases, you run in a big problem if you just pass a stream down to each one of your objects. I would imagine that your objects are organized in a tree, so XML is an exact match. (only links [ID/IDREF or XPaths as found in HREF] have to be resolved after the load process is done.)

If you start using a stream, where is the stream at when you call your Initialize() function? Do you assume it's just at the right place, magically? If so, then adding a field anywhere before that one object will eventually break its initialization.

So the way I think it should be done is a loader that knows of factories to create objects and pass down their DomElement with the data loaded from the file, memory buffer, network... then that one very simple load function can handle all the I/O problems, and each object is only responsible to check that their DomElement is valid before using it.

Personally, I would eventually use the `ostream& operator << (ostream& out)` operator for debug purposes, to print out the object and see if something's awry. This can be cool because you can simply do:

```
cout << myObj;
```

similar to what you would do in a language like Java using the .toString() function.

So if you overloaded your `<<` operator to serialize your object, especially if it serializes to binary, then that feature is not available.

One last word: in general, using functions is much more talkative than using operators, especially to do things that are not automatically what another C++ programmer would expect. In this case, I will say that the `<<` and `>>` overload would be in line with the usual usage of C++ streams and therefore it is a valid point that you bring up and I do not see any difference between using an Initialize() and (I would imagine) a Save() function, or the `<<` and `>>`. However, because of all the considerations I mentioned earlier, I do not think that your case warrant the use of streams in this way anyway.